# Escape события?

Tags: javascript

как в JS навешать не код клавишы а название клавиши ESCAPE ?
Тоесть я хочу чтобы вместо 27 - была названия клавишы

```
escClose(e) {
  if (e.keyCode === 27) {
    console.log('Closed Window ......')
  }
}
```

Comment: `e.code === 'Escape'` наверное?

Comment: а как должно работать ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Просто отслеживать событие keydown с помощью addEventListener.

```js
document.addEventListener("keydown", (e) => {
  if (e.code == "Escape") {
    console.log("Closing window...");
  }
});
```

UPD:
Вот коды и названия всех клавиш, если надо: https://snipp.ru/handbk/js-kbd-codes